# Multiple select statement in stored procedure to get the desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi all I am having two tables namely `tblTechnology` and `tblQuestions` where `tblTechnology` holds the information regarding technologies like `Asp.net, c# and all` and `tblQuestions` holds the information of `QuestionID]
      ,[QuestionTitle]
      ,[QuestionDesc]
      ,[DatePosted]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[TechID]
      ,[viewCount]
      ,[ReplyCount]`

Initially I have a written a stored procedure to get the desired result now I would like to get the latest inserted record of each technology from `tblQuestions`, this is my data in `tblquestion`

[image]

From this I would like to get the last inserted question ORDER BY Dateposted from each technology

This is what I written initially

```
 SELECT TechName,TechDesc, tblTechnology.TechID as ID, COUNT(QuestionDesc) AS 
  'Totalposts',sum(ReplyCount) as ReplyCount FROM tblTechnology LEFT JOIN 
  tblQuestions ON tblQuestions.TechID = tblTechnology.TechID 
     GROUP BY tblTechnology.TechID, TechName,TechDesc
```

which gives the result as follows

[image]

I would like to have my `QuestionTitle`, `DatePosted` and `Username` included in the result so can some one help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5fe6/5

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT top(1) WITH ties Q.TechID
        ,QuestionID
        ,QuestionTitle
        ,DatePosted
        ,Username
    FROM tblTechnology T LEFT JOIN tblQuestions Q ON Q.TechID = T.TechID
    ORDER BY row_number() over(partition BY Q.TechID ORDER BY Dateposted DESC)
)
SELECT * FROM A
OUTER apply (SELECT count(QuestionDesc) Totalposts, sum(ReplyCount) ReplyCount
    FROM tblQuestions WHERE A.TechID=tblQuestions.TechID) D
```

Comment: what is meant by `ties` here

Comment: WITH TIES: Specifies that additional rows be returned from the base result set with the same value in the ORDER BY columns appearing as the last of the TOP n (PERCENT) rows. TOP...WITH TIES can be specified only in SELECT statements, and only if an ORDER BY clause is specified.

Comment: Error `Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'TechID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Ambiguous column name 'TechID'.`

Comment: Sorry, I did not aliased that filed, should be tblQuestions.TechID. Updated query.

Comment: Ok but how can I sum up as per I did in my query to get the total posts and replys

Comment: You can use CTE and join with tblQuestions or put 2 subqueries to get that information. Just a sec, I will update a reply.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24230/discussion-between-dotnet-and-revoua)